# How to expose RestApi through https without domain name

Tags: node.js, rest, https, centos, noip

I need help with a problem. In my context I need to put a Middleware between Shopify and another cloud software. I must recieve a json from Shopify but they needs a valid https URL.
I have a Centos VPS running my app but when I generate a certificate, I receive an untrusted message and works in postman with an advice but obviously doesn’t works with Shopify. How could I proceed with this? Because my server only have an IP not a domain, so I can’t buy a certificate.

I tried to create an certificate, but I didn’t get a good result with that

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: you cannot have an SSL certificate that is not bound to a domain.
So, instead of buying an HTTPS certificate, you should go first buying a domain name and bind this to your IP.
Then you can create an SSL for free using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Of course, once you have bought your domain, you have to configure nginx or Apache on your server.